# Google Maps Place Picker package Error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-place-picker

I am getting a huge list of error when I try to run the following code with `google_maps_place_picker` package in flutter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart'
    as place;
// import 'package:location/location.dart';

import '../components/location_helper.dart';
// import '../components/location_helper.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final LatLng location1 = LatLng(37.657, -122.776);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Map Screen'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: place.PlacePicker(
              apiKey: GOOGLE_API,
              useCurrentLocation: true,
              onPlacePicked: (result) {
                print(result.addressComponents);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```

**Error**

> 5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html' show Document,
> Element, Node;
>
> Error: Not found: 'dart:js' export 'dart:js' show allowInterop,
> allowInteropCaptureThis;
>
> Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util' export 'dart:js_util';
>
> Error: Type 'Element' not found.
> Element mapDiv, [
> ^^^^^^^
>
> Error: Type 'Node' not found.   List<MVCArray> get controls =>
> ^^^^
>
> Error: Type 'Element' not found.   Element _getDiv() =>
> callMethod(this, 'getDiv', []);   ^^^^^^^

These are just some of the errors I have put. There are MANY more like these.

I have added these dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file.

```
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.2.0
  geodesy: ^0.3.2
  confirm_dialog: ^0.1.1
  geocoding: ^1.0.5
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  google_maps_place_picker: ^1.0.1
  tuple: ^1.0.3
  js: ^0.6.2
  html: ^0.14.0+4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';`

google_maps package **only supports web**. For mobile support should try out `flutter_google_places`, `google_maps_flutter` or any other package.

Comment: You saved me :(

Answer (score 0):

use this version if you got conflict error :
place_picker:
git:
url: https://github.com/lyabs243/locationpicker.git
ref: 0.10.0

if some one use place_picker and its generate conflict issue with http version package  , then use above place picker , which i define .simply just copy and past at .yml file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).