# Google Maps Place Picker Package issue in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am implementing `google_maps_picker` in my flutter application and I am facing a weird issue where the `FloatCard` result is only shown after I press the `getMyLocation` button, otherwise it just shows the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    // import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart'
        as place;
    // import 'package:location/location.dart';
    
    import '../components/location_helper.dart';
    // import '../components/location_helper.dart';
    
    class MapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final LatLng location1 = LatLng(37.657, -122.776);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Map Screen'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: place.PlacePicker(
                  apiKey: GOOGLE_API,
                  useCurrentLocation: true,
                  onPlacePicked: (result) {
                    print(result.addressComponents);
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }),
            ));
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138908/google-maps-place-picker-package-error-in-flutter) questions `accepted` answer not actually solve your problem?

Comment: It resolved my errors, but this is a new issue I am facing where the FloatCard is just loading

Comment: Did you make sure that you have granted permissions to your device to access your location?

Answer (score 0):

for ios phone
you need to use selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder instead of onPlacePicked
and add this code before return :

```
selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder: (_, selectedPlace, state, isSearchBarFocused) {

   if (Platform.isIOS) {
      if (selectedPlace != null) {
         state = SearchingState.Idle;
      }
   }

   return...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. We included `selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder` for **iOS** to update searched locations on screen, make `usePlaceDetailSearch: true` also.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart';

class MapUi extends StatelessWidget {
  final LatLng location1 = LatLng(37.657, -122.776);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: PlacePicker(
              apiKey: GoogleMap.APIKEY,
              initialPosition: location1,
              useCurrentLocation: true,
              selectInitialPosition: true,
              usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
              searchForInitialValue: true,
              onPlacePicked: (result) {
                print(result.addressComponents);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder:
                  (_, selectedPlace, state, isSearchBarFocused) {
                if (Platform.isIOS) {
                  if (selectedPlace != null) {
                    state = SearchingState.Idle;
                  }
                }

                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, left: 15),
                  child: Text(selectedPlace!.formattedAddress.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25)),
                );
              }),
        ));
  }
}
```